# How can I save a number in Firestore instead of a String?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this array where it has a color and a quantity. And when saving in Firestore, it saves as a string. How can I save the `colorStocks` in Firestore as a number?

[image]

This is how I save this in Firestore:

```
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
  const [size, setSize] = useState();
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();
  const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);


  const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...colorList];
    list[index] = { ...list[index] }; // copy the item too
    list[index][name] = value;
    setColorList(list);
  };



const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "products"), {
      prodName: productName,
      size: size + "-" + size1,
      colorList,
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  };
```

The colors text fields are dynamic, hence, I used an array:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid>
            <Grid item xs>
              //product textfield here
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs>
              //some select here
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs>
              size
              />
             
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Typography variant="h6">Colors</Typography>
          {colorList.map((singleColor, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>
                <Grid>
                  <TextField
                    label="color"
                    name="color"
                    type="text"
                    id="color"
                    required
                    value={singleColor.color}
                    onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <br />
                <Grid>
                  <TextField
                    label="Stocks"
                    name="colorStocks"
                    type="text"
                    id="colorStocks"
                    required
                    value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                    onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </div>
              <br />
              <Grid item xs>
               //button to remove color
              </Grid>
              <br />
              //button to add color
            </div>
          ))}
          <br />
          <Divider />
          <br />
          <Grid item xs>
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </Grid>
        </form>
```

Is there way where I could destructure `colorList` to save it as a `Number()` in firestore? Or what are the other ways this would be solved? This should be as a number since this would be subtracted later on.

The `colorList` in console:
[image]

Comment: You can convert `colorStocks` to number in  `handleColorChange`. Share  `handleColorChange` method pls.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Hello, added it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert `colorStocks` to number before sending to Firestore.

```
const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setColorList(prevState => {
        let list = [...prevState];
        list[index][name] = name === 'colorStocks' ? +value : value;
        return list;
    });
  };
```